# jdk warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

Tags: java

I am trying to run a simple api test using karateframework and i got following error while execution.

```
Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
```

[image]

After going through the contentfrom google, i came to know the solution is to add arguments. But the program argument is disabled. Please help me in resoving the issue

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the difference between errors and warnings in the build?

Comment: In a **future** release. Not today. And in that eventual future, download [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) (or use [Graal](https://www.graalvm.org/)) and get back to work.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is an XY problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: i stiall have the same issue after changing from openjdk to Graal.
Error: Java : error: release version 5 is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Intuit Karate does not support Java 14. The [GitHub - intuit/karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) page says (in part)

> Any Java version from 8-12 is supported.

Comment: I changed the java version to Graal and open jdk 12. Even then i have the same issue.

Comment: @satishp5846 you are certainly missing something, works for me